# HTTPS уведомление о платеже Yoomoney и запуск письма из PHP. jQwery post

Tags: javascript, php

Всем привет.

Настроил уведомление о успешном платеже из Yoomoney. PHP файл простой и в нем лежит письмо для отправки. С функцией mail.

Вопрос, как запустить php файл при приходе в него POST уведомления. Читал, что это делается с помощью jQwery POST запросов. Перепробовал разные варианты. Но не понимаю, как это реализовать.

Просто не умею пока работать с js и библиотеками.

Как это можно реализовать, запуск файла. Если есть с примером кода.

Comment: Там куда приходит уведомление о платеже, после сверки контрольной подписи разместить mail()

Comment: Как оказалось, я просто невнимательный человек по ночам ) После первой строки стоял -   exit(); И дальше рабочий код начинался. Но спасибо за помощь. А я потратил на это кучу времени. Будет уроком мне!